# How can I make a knockout "value" binding write-only so it doesn't try to read from it?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
<input data-bind="value: fileName" type="file" multiple="">
<input data-bind="value: fileName" type="text" readonly="">
```

This works except I get:

`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

because it tries to set the value of the file input when I only want to read it and write it to the text input.

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/esk5akwj/2/

- Check box.
- Choose a file.
- Check box again.
- Try to choose a file again.

Comment: Surely you have this the wrong way round - its not that you want to make one `value` binding write-only, its that you want to make one read--only (the one bound to the `file` input box).

Comment: Could you explain your question, the setting you have submitted seems to work fine, http://jsfiddle.net/esk5akwj/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. That's exactly what I want to do and it works at first except when the element is re-rendered by the parent it causes knockout to try to set the value of the input[file] which isn't allowed.

Comment: @Lordbalmon http://jsfiddle.net/esk5akwj/2/

Comment: Seems like the right thing to do is to make a wrapper for the value binding that resets the value to empty string on init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file chooser value can only be set by using the file chooser, and must start as the empty string, you need a custom binding handler that wraps the `value` binding and on init sets the bound value to the empty string:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.resetValue = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    valueAccessor()('');
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  fileName: ko.observable(),
  c: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="checked: c" type="checkbox">Check me, choose a file, uncheck me, check me, choose a file.

<!-- ko if: c -->
<input data-bind="resetValue: fileName" type="file" multiple="">
<input data-bind="value: fileName" type="text" readonly>
<!-- /ko -->
```